# How to remove only tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to remove the span using jQuery,
I have tried the `.unwrap();` but it's not working.

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>link</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>link</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And how are you trying to do that, why is it not working and what is it doing?

Comment: It's likely that you're query is wrong, unwrap() should do the trick. Please provide more information!

Comment: it shows .unwrap() is not a function. :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Obviously, `unwrap` doesn't work as the `span`s only have text nodes inside them and jquery doesn't handle text nodes too well... this works however (you could use also `jQuery.text` instead of `jQuery.html` if you're sure that the `span` only contains text):

```
$('li a span').replaceWith($('li a span').html());
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/uviko)

**Edit**: Actually, it seems that `unwrap` works as well if you use [`jQuery.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to work around the jquery's inability to directly select text nodes:

```
$('li a span').contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').find('span').remove();
```

or

```
$('li').find('span').detach();
```

If you want to remove the wrapping only, try

```
var buffer = $('li').find('span').text();
$('li').find('span').parent().html(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap should work.  It's possible you're not successfully selecting the span which you wish to unwrap.  You can try the following code which should select that span successfully:

```
$("li a span").unwrap()
```

It's a bit unclear from your question what exactly you're trying to do.  It's also unclear whether you're having trouble with the selectors or with the jquery api.  To get a better handle on jquery's selectors I recommend you install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [firequery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), as it can really help you understand what you're selecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).text();
    $(this).remove();
    $("a").html(content);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.remove()
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

:)

Comment: I think he wants to remove the 'span'-tag without removing its content, i.e. `unwrap` (which it seems he's unable to get working)

Comment: Oh - I suppose so, bit pre-emptive with the "remove the span using jQuery" :(