# jquery/javascript unwrap all

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

i have this:

```
<div>All <span class="hl">text</span> should <span class="hl">be <span class="hl">unwrapped</span> <span>but not me</span> </span></div>
```

how to remove all spans (with class="h1") to get this?

```
<div>All text should be unwrapped <span>but not me</span></div>
```

ps: would consider javascript Regex or jquery solution

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/44084

Comment: if the spans are always like this, I would consider replacing them (opening and closing) by empty string... but that's because I'm no good with regex :-)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719078/how-to-remove-only-tag-using-jquery

Comment: I think you should really explain using words what you want. Are you now saying that the unwrapping should affect spans with a class `"h1"`?

Comment: Oh god! Who put negative vote for all answers??

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery:

```
$("span.hl").contents().unwrap();
```

will do what you want for that specific line of code, but you may have to use differing selectors if your code changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span .h1').contents().unwrap();
```

This code will do

Comment: This produces: `<div>All text should be <span class="hl">unwrapped</span>
</div>`